# HTTP 503 on Instagram API requests

Tags: javascript, http, instagram

From time to time I get the famous 503 (service unavailable) HTTP error
when requesting https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent.

The relevant access token is not being overloaded at all (not even getting close to the 5000/hour limit)
What could possibly be the reason for that?
could it relate to the fact I'm authenticating my users (getting my Instagram access token) on server side?

I really need some help here,
It just seem to be completely random whether I get valid data back
or this evil 503...

Many thanks!

Comment: 503 typically means the servers are overloaded. If you are only seeing this intermittently then that's probably the case. I have times when I get a "Couldn't refresh feed" within Instagram, so they probably have the same issues within their app as well.

Comment: You just need to check for this http error and retry after a second or two.

Comment: this is happening to lots of people this afternoon: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/DTRC_u0CYHk

Comment: Ok, starting to realize it is probably something global (Instagram side). Thanks you all guys